# Using ngModel with Angular Material Mat-Menu and

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I am using Angular Material to add menus. I got the following code working but I use the (click) event to pass the selected year to the typescript to set the selectedYear. In my last project, I used regular bootstrap with [(ngModel)]. I read thru the angular.material.io website and did not see any example with ngModel binding to the year menu selection. I did see  but that is with mat-option. Is there a way to use ngModel to archieve cleaner Angular code and avoid the need to call function to set the selection? Thanks

```
<mat-menu #yearMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="OnClickedYear(year)" class="bread-crumb-mat-menu-item" *ngFor="let year of years"> {{year}} </button>
</mat-menu>
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="yearMenu" class="bread-crumb">{{selectedYear}}<mat-icon>expand_more</mat-icon></button>
```

Comment: `ngModel` is used for input controls like `<input type="text"` and `<select`. I don't see how that applies to a menu and how you would expect that to work...

Comment: If you need a `mat-menu` to be a custom control that can be used with template-driven and/or reactive forms, you can wrap it with a custom component and create a custom input control, there are plenty of examples of creating custom controls available out there. Or you could simply use a `mat-select` instead of a `mat-menu` which is an actual input and has built in support to work with forms modules and `ngModel`.